# Angular material v15 : Not able to click on icon inside mat tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have added a `(click)` handler on icon inside `mat-tab > mat-tab-label`

But the problem is its not getting triggered when I click on the `mat-icon`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-waqy4a-5p9wpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html)

Code:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <mat-icon (click)="alertRef()" class="example-tab-icon">delete</mat-icon>
      Third
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside each tab of your mat-tab-group, there's an element with class `mdc-tab__content` by default this element has a `pointer-events: none` property. You can easily target this element and use `pointer-events: all` instead.

Something like this:

(In your SCSS file)

```
:host {
   ::ng-deep {
     .mat-mdc-tab-group .mat-mdc-tab .mdc-tab__content { pointer-events: all; }
   }
}
```

Comment: add opacity: initial; to the css to get the button not to look disabled. i made a global css like this 
```.mdc-tab.mat-mdc-tab:has(.fake-disabled){
  opacity: initial;
  .mdc-tab__content {
    pointer-events: all;
  }
}``` 
and put a class on the button called fake-disabled